# How can I get the impact velocity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

OnCollisionEnter I am calculating the magnitude to determine whether or not to play a sound clip. Which works fine for most of the collisions, but it is triggering with my ball that is rolling on a plane. Since the ball is moving at a relatively fast speed and the magnitude doesn't take direction into account, every time it rolls it plays the clip. Sometimes 15 times a second. I only want the clip to play when the ball is dropped on the plane. Does anybody have some suggestions or solutions to calculate the impact velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying to check if the object's velocity is in your threshold, you could narrow down the collisions checked via using object tags.

More info about [rigidbody velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

*edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the impact angle between the surface normal and the relative impact velocity and take it into account.

```csharp
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
  Vector3 velocity = collision.relativeVelocity;
  Vector3 normal = collision.GetContac(0).normal;
  if (velocity.magnitude > 2)//impact faster than 2
  {
    if (Vector3.Angle(normal, velocity) > 60)//impact angle greater than 60
    {
      audioSource.Play();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-impulse.html